# when object is deleted from s3 bucket and analyze in Cloudwatch log insight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

When i delete object and  get object in s3 bucket so that i got in "GetObject" "requestParameters.key" object name and their path similarly when i "DeleteObjects" in s3 bucket i didn't get any object name and their path.

fields @timestamp, eventName, requestParameters.key
| filter (eventName = "DeleteObjects" or eventName = "GetObject")
| sort @timestamp desc

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m45GP.png)

Anyone can done this question solution, ping me !

Comment: Did you try to expand the logs and check for difference between the response of DeleteObjects and GetObject events?

Comment: Also your question and title are so vague.